# MathJax boilerplate

Tags: discussion, comments

We had a [MathJax question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109363/how-to-number-multiline-equations) just now that was unceremoniously closed as off topic.  As it probably should be.  But I feel like we should, if we can, direct the questioner some place elsewhere there might find an answer.  I'm asking the community for suggested comments and phrasing.

Comment: See also [How do we feel about MathJaX/jsMath/other spin-offs?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/272)

Comment: @Martin: I agree with the answers there.  MathJax questions are not off topic if they are about syntax, but are off topic if they are about the JavaScript or HTML side of things.  Also, it's not that we don't *want* to answer questions like that, it's that we don't *know* the answers to questions like that.

Comment: It's probably more don't want to answer here really (I'm on the mathjax steering committee (I think:-) so I'm probably supposed to know something about it:-) Good proposed answer by the way. The mj google groups forum is better but politically it's good to mention SO mathjax tag and keep things in the sx world. I usually try to answer mj questions in comments (but then vote to close anyway)

Comment: This came up again today with actuarial notation question and again someone downvoted (I upvoted to compensate) downvoting a new user to -ve rep just because he asked a mathjax question seems excessive.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is my proposed answer:

`While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site.  You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users) Google group.`

Comment: Good thinking. Why don't you add it to the [text building blocks](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)?

Comment: That's the eventual destination, to be sure.  I wanted to isolate the discussion around this particular building block first.  There being no objection, I will probably integrate it soon.

Comment: This is inline with the existing tag wiki so I don't think there can be any objection to it really (the fact that people post here despite the tag wiki suggests perhaps they are not as visible as they might be)

Comment: Maybe better, instead of "it is not TeX/LaTeX...", but "it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic...".  I edited the Mathjax tag wiki along these lines; my edit is in the queue.

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited the [building block question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430) with the snippet above.  If anyone wants to edit further just go there.

Comment: A minor comment: the word "instead" is misspelled "insteead". Same typo also occurred in the [Text building blocks post](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks)

Comment: @KevinC: thanks.  I updated the building blocks post.

Comment: Shouldn't we extend that "Text Building Block" to MathML too? See [this MathML question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114960/is-it-possible-to-use-mathml-to-describe-data-tables), for instance.

Comment: IMO That is a separate block. But same language: although TeX and MathML are both used for math, MathML is off topic, try these places instead.

Comment: Stack Overflow is two words.

Comment: @TRiG: so edited (and on the building blocks meta post).

Comment: @E.P.: updated.